# Building Unreal Engine 5 project with Visual Studio for Linux - ld.lld : error

Tags: linux, linker-errors, unreal-engine5, assimp

I am trying to build a Dedicated Server for an Unreal Engine 5 Project for Linux from Visual Studio.

The project contains a Plugin `(UE4_Assimp)` that relies on an external library `(Assimp)` for the import of 3D objects/models into the game at runtime. It could be that the Plugin is compiled for Windows only, though this is of no concern for the Dedicated Server build of my application: the import functionality is not needed in the Server Build so I excluded it from that build configuration by adding:
`DisablePlugins.Add("UE4_Assimp");`
to the `MyGameServer.Target.cs` file. Regardless, the project can not be build from Visual Studio since the linker cannot access a file related to that Plugin.

```
71>ld.lld : error : cannot open C:/<project dir>/Plugins/UE4_Assimp/Source/ThirdParty/UE_AssimpLibrary/assimp/bin\libassimp.so: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
71>clang++ : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
71>Failed to link C:\<project dir>\Binaries\Linux\MyGameServer after 10 retries
71>[2/2] WriteMetadata MyGameServer.target cancelled
71>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(45,5): error MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\TheaterDo_Medienabt\Documents\UE\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat MyGameServer Linux Development -Project="C:\<project dir>\MyGame.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
71>Done building project "MyGame.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
... (some more lines without errors) ...
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 69 skipped ==========
```

However, the specified file `libassimp.so` exists in the given directory. The file permission are set to read and write for anybody. It was compiled/build on a WSL 2 Ubuntu with cmake.

Building the Dedicated Server for Win64 works without Help tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the linker is able to access the depending shared-object-library assimp.so

```
71>ld.lld : error : cannot open C:/<project dir>/Plugins/UE4_Assimp/Source/ThirdParty/UE_AssimpLibrary/assimp/bin\libassimp.so: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

My gues why the so file cannot be found is the backshlash in your path. Try to fix this one shall help you.

Comment: I was suspicious about the backslash, too. However, I have no idea where this arose from or how to address it. The file was copied from the wsl - I will look into it again.